# Can a standard computer function as a radio receiver without additional hardware, and how?

Tags: radio, transmitter, receiver

Can a standard computer function as a radio receiver without additional hardware, and how?

Thanks, and happy holidays.

Comment: [Software defined radio (SDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio), essentially, turns a computer into a radio.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49853/discussion-on-question-by-listen-can-a-standard-computer-function-as-a-radio-rec).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No. You can often however get it to *transmit* radio, even if you don't want it to.

Long answer: This is going to depend on your definition of standard. Just as every bit of wire is potentially a transmitter, so is every wire a receiver. I used to have a set of those cheap computer stereo speakers that would "pick up" GSM transmissions (google "TDMA noise"). Every time I received a text message I got a few seconds of "bip" noises from the speakers beforehand.

The general way of doing it is software defined radio, as mentioned above, which can now be done with $10 devices designed as TV receivers but capable of broader tuning.

More sensibly, stick to existing RF modules: bluetooth, wifi, ISM band (433 or 969MHz), or the rather nice ones from Nordic Semiconductor.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you. So good to see there are still some cool people on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of "radio receiver".  Many (most?) modern computers have receivers built in.  Wi-Fi, BlueTooth, etc. They have both transmit and receive functionality for digital data in those frequency ranges (like 2.4GHz)  If you mean "radio receiver" like something to listen to broadcast entertainment radio (AM/MW, FM, etc.) then the answer is no.